# UITextFieldDelegate != IBAction backgroundTap

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, iphone-sdk-3.1

The scope of this question is IPhone 3.1 sdk (app running in simulator still)

I have a table view that has a cell with a UITextField in that cell.  The table view is grouped, and has one section with just a couple fields.  Im NOT using IB so backgroundTap is out of the question (as far as i can tell at least).  When i click the text field, keyboard shows.  Hiding it is still troublesome.  Ive pulled the UITextFieldDelegate into the mix to hide the keyboard but the textFieldShouldEndEditing method doesnt seem to fire when the background is tapped (when i mean background, im tapping outside of the grouped table view section).  First off, should it?

textFieldShouldReturn fires with no problem and i can resign at this point but shouldnt i be able to resign if focus shifts away from that control?

Any help is much appreciated
-me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you'll only stop editing a field when you:

- hit the "Done" or action button on the keyboard
- begin editing another field
- exit the view
- have another button on screen that removes focus

From any of these, you can call -[textField resignFirstResponder] to dismiss the keyboard and call your -textFieldShouldEndEditing: method. There's no reason that just tapping on a non-active part of the screen should dismiss the keyboard.